# Liqpay передать значение input

Tags: php

Добрый день, пытаюсь реализовать оплату на сайте через liqpay. Пользователь заполняет форму и после после нажатия на кнопку его перекидывает на страницу liqpay. Вот не могу понять как я могу передать в массив Data например в свойство description данные которые пользователь указал в форме.

Вот код самой формы

```
<form class="row" method="POST" action="https://www.liqpay.com/api/checkout">
 <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $data; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo $signature; ?>" />
 <input type="text" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя*">
 <input type="text" name="liqpay-email" placeholder="Введите Ваш e-mail*">
 <input type="text" name="liqpay-phone" class="number" placeholder="+38 (___) ___-__-__">
 <button type="submit" class="header-button">Зарегистрироваться</button>
</form>
```

$data и $signature выводяться из другого файла

Comment: Судя по их документации вы не можете получить не задокументированные поля с использованием стандартных средств. Пишите велосипед. Используйте js + ajax и перехватывайте отправку формы, отправляя к себе на сервер дополнительные данные. Или генерируйте адрес возврата (в зависимости от дополнительных полей) в data (да и сами все данные из data) на js перед отправкой формы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял из документации, вы должны сформировать массив data, закодировать его в base64, а потом отправить уже на API процессор LiqPay.
То есть, сначала, получаем от пользователя необходимые данные (description). Формируем новую форму для API предварительно подготовив через

```
new LiqPay($public_key, $private_key)->cnb_form([
    'action'         => 'pay',
    'amount'         => '1',
    'currency'       => 'USD',
    'description'    => $_POST['description'],
    'order_id'       => 'order_id_1',
    'version'        => '3'
]);
```

Тут нюанс скорее в другом. Зачем? Это поле - описание платежа. Но это не мои заботы, хозяин барин.

С другой стороны, вам не нужна библиотека от LiqPay для работы. Вы можете самостоятельно реализовать то что вам нужно, без ее использования. И получите необходимую гибкость.

Модифицируйте

```
LiqPay::cnb_form()
```

так как вам нужно и все проблемы будут решены.

Резюмируя:
1. Подготовили данные, сгенерировали ключ из json-а, отправили на LiqPay.
2. Изменили методы класса LiqPay под свои нужны. 
LiqPay будет проводить валидацию запроса на уровне своего Api-процессора, а то каким способом вы прислали данные - не важно.